# Getting error when trying to Cancel the recurring subscription using API

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I have PayPal Website Payments Standard configured in my site. User can subscribe the membership with Paypal Recurring. I have adde API to cancel the subscription using  "ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus". But it returns the error "The profile ID is invalid".

But the Profile ID in the API call is same as the Profile id in the Paypal . ID is like *S-79440077XXXXXXXXX*.

API Call

> USER=%USERNAME% &PWD=%PASSWORD% &SIGNATURE=%SIGNATURE% &VERSION=76.0
>   &METHOD=ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus
>   &PROFILEID=S-79440077XXXXXXXXX &ACTION=Cancel
>   &NOTE=Profile+cancelled+at+store

Response

> TIMESTAMP=2018-03-01 T06:59:10Z &CORRELATIONID=b445f660c29d8
>   &ACK=Failure &VERSION=76.0 &BUILD=39949200 &L_ERRORCODE0=11552
>   &L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Invalid profile ID &L_LONGMESSAGE0=The profile ID is
>   invalid &L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error

Please help to resolve the issue.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The API operation ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatusRequest doesn't support PayPal Subscriptions (S-XXXX). The API operation works for only recurring profiles(I-XXXX) which were created via express checkout recurring payments.

You are passing the subscription id(S-XXX) as I-XXXX profile in the API request by replacing the S with I as I-7XXXXXXXXXXXX4R, this is an invalid I-XXXX profile, hence you are receiving the error as an Invliad profile.

If you pass the correct S-XXX profile value in the API request then you will get the error-- Subscription profiles are not supported for recurring payments.